# Django : TemplateDoesNotExist at /.../

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render a simple page, but I encountered a problem.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /pages/  
{}
```

The template folder is not found. here is my configurations of **settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pages/template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Have I done something wrong ?

*--------------- CMD ----------------*

```
Internal Server Error: /pages/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\src\pages\views.py", line 6, in index
    return render('index.html', context)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
    template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 43, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: {}
[12/Jan/2016 20:51:57] "GET /pages/ HTTP/1.1" 500 74646
```

----------- UPDATE -------------

**File Tree**

[image]

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: please post your project directory structure.

Comment: @Saturnix Updated it

Comment: move your template folder outside of "pages" and call it "templates". Put in your settings: `TEMPLATE_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)`. Now, in your views.py call the template with `render('index.html', context)`

Comment: @Saturnix Renamed template to templates, moved it into the src subfolder, modified settings, but still got the same error message. (I updated views.py file, just in case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have forgotten the first argument `request` when you call `render`.

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

You can have multiple template directories, e.g. `src/template` and `pages/template`. If you want to have a `src/template` directory, then you need to include it in your `DIRS` option`.

```
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

You don't need `pages/templates` in the `DIRS` directory -- templates in that directory will be found by the app loader because you have `APP_DIRS` set to `True`, and `pages` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: You can have multiple templates folders if you want. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

You probably forgot to add your app in Installed_Apps setting.

INSTALLED_APPS = [

## ...

```
'your_app'
```

]

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong route of your templates.
By default django have the folder "template" for html files, try create folder called template inside your app folder and inside them the file index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this mistake:

> TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain) django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html

when I used to make a virtual environment via PyCharm since it didn't install all the required tools for templates to be loaded from your templates folder.

I now create my [virtual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) [environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) through command prompt and install Django and anything else that I need with pip install "something".

**Note:**
I know that this doesn't answer the question, but this is what I did wrong. I stumbled upon this question, so might others who had the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if correct application name is declared in settings.py file and also check

```
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templatefoldername') and TEMPLATES = [


 {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
```

is correct.please also check in views.py html file name mentioned is correct.(`return render(request, 'details/htmlfile', context=my_dict)`)

Answer (score 1):

you just require to mention name of the folder in which your html file resides.

`'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`
and coming back to your view.py file just keep it as follows

```
return render(request, 'file_name.html')
-- run the server
```